# Symfony2: Redirect to requested path

Tags: redirect, symfony, controller

I want to redirect the user back to the path from which he started the request.

Example:
/profile

/profile/edit

/profile

OR:

/products

/profile/edit

/products

What do I have to set for this redirection mode?

Answer (score 1):

Inside your controller for `/profile/edit` you can capture the page they came from with `$request->headers->get('referer')`.

If `/profile/edit` is a page with a single form, I'd probably just add a hidden field that says where the redirect should go.

```
public function editAction(Request $request)
{
    // If you have a POST value coming from the user, it will be used, otherwise
    // assume this is the first time they landed on the page and grab the current 
    // referer. With this method it doesn't matter how many times they submit the form
    // you won't accidentally overwrite the referer URL with /profile/edit. That could
    // lead to a confusing loop.
    $referer = $request->request->get('referer', $request->headers->get('referer'));

    if ($formIsSaved)
    {
        return new RedirectResponse($referer)
    }

    return array(
        // Your template should include a hidden field in the form that returns this.
        'referer' => $referer,
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pass a redirect path as a GET parameter — say, `redirectTo` — to the edit page and after the edit process is complete, redirect to that path.

```php
return new RedirectResponse($request->query->get('redirectTo');
```

You could make it more robust by checking whether or not that parameter is provided, and if it isn't, redirect to some sort of a default path.

Comment: Hi, I would like to avoid messing around with the GET parameters :)
Couldn't the session be used for something like this?

Comment: It will get very messy with sessions — been there, done that.